# input is self closing and should not have content Jade-Lang issues

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, pug

I'm currently working through some Node.js ExpressJS and MongoDB and have hit a snag with the Jade.  I keep getting an `input is self closing and should not have content` error when I go to my newuser page.  I've checked everything on this site, been through the jade-lang docs and have come up short, could really use some guidance with this Jade shenanigans.  Thanks everyone!!

Here is my code:

```
extends layout


block content
  h1= title
  form#formAddUser(name="adduser",method="post",action="/adduser")
    input#inputUserName(type="text", placeholder="username", name="username")
      input#inputUserEmail(type="text", placeholder="useremail", name="useremail")
        button#btnSubmit(type="submit", value="submit")
```

And here is my error message:

`/home/evan/dev/nodetest1/views/newuser.jade:7 5| //- h1= title 6| form#formAddUser(name="adduser",method="post",action="/adduser") > 7| input#inputUserName(type="text", placeholder="username", name="username") 8| input#inputUserEmail(type="text", placeholder="useremail", name="useremail") 9| button#btnSubmit(type="submit", value="submit") 10| input is self closing and should not have content.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error says exactly what the problem is, but unless you know how to translate it, that doesn't mean it's easy to understand :D

```
input#inputUserName(type="text", placeholder="username", name="username")
  input#inputUserEmail(type="text", placeholder="useremail", name="useremail")
    button#btnSubmit(type="submit", value="submit")
```

will try to put `#inputUserEmail` inside `#inputUserName` and `#btnSubmit` inside `#inputUserEmail` because of the indentation. It should just be

```
input#inputUserName(type="text", placeholder="username", name="username")
input#inputUserEmail(type="text", placeholder="useremail", name="useremail")
button#btnSubmit(type="submit", value="submit")
```

This is because in HTML, `<input>` elements do not have children, so the nesting is not allowed.

Comment: Thank you so much.  Didn't even think that Jade was indent sensitive, but that makes total sense.  Again, thanks for the help.